# What does つけ in "うそつけ" mean?

Tags: meaning

The context is the following: in a manga there are 2 characters talking. One of them says something and the other says back to him, "うそつけ!!". It is translated as "Liar!!". I understand that "うそ" means "a lie". What about "つけ"?